# Is there a way to hint that an attribute can't be None in certain circumstances?

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I'm trying to avoid having a bunch of `if`s or `assert`s in the code using this class.

```py
class TemplateRow(tp.NamedTuple):
    """Parsed template row, if not error."""

    template: Template | None = None
    error: str | None = None

    @property
    def valid(self) -> bool:
        """Determine if this row is valid.

        Returns:
            bool: is this template row valid
        """
        return self.error is None


def read_template(filename: str | Path) -> tp.Iterator[TemplateRow]:
    """Read a TSV file into a list of templates.

    Args:
        filename (str): Path to the TSV file

    Yields:
        TemplateRow : parsed template row, or error message
    """
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
        for row in reader:
            try:
                yield TemplateRow(template=Template.parse_obj(row))
            except pydantic.ValidationError as e:
                yield TemplateRow(error=str(e))
```

So, I read in a TSV and try to convert it to a Pydantic model with a bunch of validators. If it works, I return the filled-in model.
If it fails, I return the validation error string

To make the caller be able to just expect one type, I return a NamedTuple which can contain the parsed model instance, or an error string.

There's a simple property to say if it's valid, mainly for readability and for a possible future enhancement.

Anyway, if I have a loop such as:

```py
ok: list[Template]=[]
notok: list[str] = []

for row in read_template(file):
    if row.valid:
       ok.append(row.template)
    else:
       notok.append(row.error)
```

I will get mypy errors that row.error might be None

As I've already checked the `.valid` property, it can't be.

Is there anyway to communicate this to type checkers?

thanks

Comment: `str(row.error)` ?  the bottom line is that python is not a strongly typed language and the "typing" it does have is lacking in many ways and you will have to do hacky workarounds

Comment: Thanks, Joran. Yeah I was just hoping something like a TypeGuard might help. I did consider returning either a `Template` or a `str` from the function and doing an `isinstance` in the caller but it seemed a pretty hacky workaround

Comment: @Joran Not sure what exactly you mean by "not strongly typed" (Python is generally described as strongly typed!) but other languages with static type checking would have the same issue with this code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yeah i misspoke ... but still many other languages have something like `row.error!.toString()` for this sort of thing  I was really just saying there is no such operators in python (there are some pep proposals ... but afaik they are still not implemented)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Python **is** strongly typed. It happens to be **dynamically** (i.e. not _statically_) typed.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I blame covid brain :P

Comment: @Wardy I don't understand the need for `TemplateRow` at all. Why not just collect parsed `Template` objects and validation error messages directly?

Comment: _"To make the caller be able to just expect one type ..."_ Can you elaborate on why this is important to you? All it seems to accomplish is force that namedtuple-workaround, when you can just have the iterator yield either `Template` instances or `ValidationError` instances (for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `TypeGuard`, you could actually define two types - `ValidTemplateRow` and `InvalidTemplateRow`. Then, simply use `isinstance` to check for either.

```py
class ValidTemplateRow(tp.NamedTuple):
    template: Template


class InvalidTemplateRow(tp.NamedTuple):
    error: str


def read_template(filename: str | Path) -> tp.Iterator[InvalidTemplateRow | ValidTemplateRow]:
    """Read a TSV file into a list of templates.

    Args:
        filename (str): Path to the TSV file

    Yields:
        TemplateRow : parsed template row, or error message
    """
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
        for row in reader:
            try:
                yield ValidTemplateRow(template=Template.parse_obj(row))
            except pydantic.ValidationError as e:
                yield InvalidTemplateRow(error=str(e))


ok: list[Template] = []
notok: list[str] = []

for row in read_template("file"):
    if isinstance(row, ValidTemplateRow):
        ok.append(row.template)
    else:
        notok.append(row.error)
```

Comment: Hi Paweł, this is similar to something I had along the way. I was trying to avoid the `if isinstance` but yes, I think I've overcomplicated it. Nothing really wrong with doing it this way, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the restriction of having the iterator yield only one type.

Why not just do it like this?

```py
import csv
from collections.abc import Iterator
from pathlib import Path

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError


class Template(BaseModel):
    foo: str
    bar: int


def read_template(filename: str | Path) -> Iterator[Template | ValidationError]:
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
        for row in reader:
            try:
                yield Template.parse_obj(row)
            except ValidationError as e:
                yield e


def main() -> None:
    ok: list[Template] = []
    notok: list[str] = []
    for obj in read_template("path/to/file.tsv"):
        if isinstance(obj, Template):
            ok.append(obj)
        else:
            notok.append(str(obj))
    ...
```

This seems to accomplish the same thing without the need for `TemplateRow`. If you have a good reason for that restriction, please elaborate.

Comment: thanks Daniil, agreed. Yes, similar to Pawel's point above. Thanks for taking the time to reply :)